# python PIL or pyautogui.screeshot("photo.png",region=(xx,yy,zz)) error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot, pyautogui, built-in

```
from pyautogui import screenshot
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
screenshot("photo.png",region=(xx,yy,zz))
im = Image.open('photo.png')
```

after executing this code, on kali linux, that takes a screenshot of a portion of the screen it creates other files as "photo_000.png" because of using a while; and i face sometimes this error but not always;

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 476, in _screenshot_linux
im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2891, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

what is the problem on my code.
Note that scrot is already installed.
Thanks a lot

Comment: i guess you have to give full path of your images where it is saved

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all. The `region` parameter to `screenshot()` should be a 4-tuple, not 3. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Your wording says you use a `while` loop, but your code does not. Please show your actual code or at least accurately representative code.